# Vim: Confused about usage of linebreak when textwidth is enabled

Tags: vim

I have textwidth set to 130 characters for text files. I see no visible change in using linebreak. Even without linebreak the text wraps at the end of words when I **resize** the window. I am confused about the relation between linebreak and textwidth. Can you please explain? Reading help files in vim did not help me with this.

My .vim/ftplugin/text.vim

```
set textwidth=130
set linebreak
```

My .vimrc file

```
  1 set nocompatible
  2 
  3 "Setting Tab width
  4 set tabstop=4
  5 set softtabstop=4
  6 set shiftwidth=4
  7 set expandtab
  8 
  9 "Setting Line numbers
 10 set number
 11 
 12 "Set up incremental search using incsearch
 13 set incsearch
 14 
 15 "Set ignore case for search optin
 16 set ignorecase
 17 
 18 "Set highlight when searching a vim doc
 19 set hlsearch
 20 
 21 "Settings for text files
 22 autocmd  FileType text source ~/.vim/ftplugin/text.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want hard wrapping with newlines? In that case you should make sure you have

```
set formatoptions+=tq  " enable automatic hard wrap and the gq motion
```

in your vimrc.

Then use gq{count}j or gq{count}k tore-format lines you want to.

Linebreak defines whether to VIRTUALLY wrap lines between words or not.

Comment: Even without the `set linebreak` in `.vimrc` words are wrapped automatically. I can't understand how that is happening.

I opened the .vim/ftplugin/text.vim and removed the 'set linebreak' but it still works. DO I have to restart vim for these things to take effect?

Comment: While 'linebreak' controls whether to wrap between words when doing "soft" wrapping, the option that controls whether to soft-wrap at all is 'wrap'. You'd need to remove both before seeing any change. And for filetype plugins, you don't need to re-load Vim; but you DO need to re-set the filetype. Either do `:e` or do `:set ft=text` to reload the filetype.

Comment: @Ben- Thank you. How do I remove softwrap? I am under the assumption that softwrap is enabled by default. I don't see anything in my settings enabling softwrap. Also, how do I reload Vim instead of just resetting a file type?